# MP3s/Youtube have stopped playing

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mate-desktop

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with the Mate 1.8.2 desktop.

A couple of days ago, i had a strange issue where I couldn't play an mp4 video in Chrome.  I rebooted and it was fine.

Then, at some point yesterday I completely lost the ability to play audio files completely.  Even after a reboot, I can no longer play mp3, flac, or m4a.  I've tried in Chrome, the built in media player, two different music apps and audacity.  In all of them, they seem to open fine but when I press play it just stops instantly without making a noise.

I played a MOV video file and the video works but there's no audio.  If I open a youtube video it just stalls with the spinning circle.

I'm stumped...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I had an online music studio site open in one of my chrome tabs, and that was somehow blocking all audio from being played across my whole system.  As soon as i closed the tab, 10 different audio streams all burst into life at the same time - all the things i'd been trying to play.

Weird.